# Airflow UI is not launching in browser

Tags: python, amazon-ec2, airflow, airflow-webserver

I am unable to open webUI of Airflow & How to get all dags info & code from Terminal/AWS

After this command

```
airflow webserver -p 8080
```

[image]
/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/models/base.py:49 MovedIn20Warning: [31mDeprecated API features detected! These feature(s) are not compatible with SQLAlchemy 2.0. [32mTo prevent incompatible upgrades prior to updating applications, ensure requirements files are pinned to "sqlalchemy<2.0". [36mSet environment variable SQLALCHEMY_WARN_20=1 to show all deprecation warnings.  Set environment variable SQLALCHEMY_SILENCE_UBER_WARNING=1 to silence this message.[0m (Background on SQLAlchemy 2.0 at: https://sqlalche.me/e/b8d9)

---

____    |**( )**_______  **/**  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ***/*  /* __  /*  __ _ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  **/ _  / / /*/ /* |/ |/ /
*/*/  |*/*/  /*/    /*/    /*/  _***/____/|__/
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/bin/airflow", line 8, in 
sys.exit(main())
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/**main**.py", line 39, in main
args.func(args)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/cli_parser.py", line 52, in command
return func(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/cli.py", line 108, in wrapper
return f(*args, **kwargs)
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/cli/commands/webserver_command.py", line 370, in webserver
check_if_pidfile_process_is_running(pid_file=pid_file, process_name="webserver")
File "/home/ubuntu/.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/airflow/utils/process_utils.py", line 317, in check_if_pidfile_process_is_running
raise AirflowException(f"The {process_name} is already running under PID {pid}.")
airflow.exceptions.AirflowException: The webserver is already running under PID 2621372.

Answer (score 1):

The error is saying you already have a webserver running, either from an earlier `airflow webserver` command launch that didn't exit properly, or it's actually running as expected already.

You should kill the existing webserver process on the PID specified in the error message and restart the webserver:

`kill -9 2621372`